# If a parameter is of type T&& is it passed by move or by reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I hope this isn't a silly question, I just wanted to make sure my understanding on this is clear.

If a parameter is received by RValue reference :

```
struct A { /* move and copy constructors here... */ };
template <class T> void f1(T&&) {

}
void demo()
{
    f1(A());
    f1(std::move<A>(A()));
}
```

It seems to me that it is passed by reference, and no move constructor is applied.

Is this true?
I just wanted to make sure there is no copy elision or other optimization here.

Comment: Note that the meaning of `T&&` depends on whether `T` is a template parameter or not.

Comment: A reference is always a reference (of some sort). You don't get moves/copies until you start dealing with values.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. A constructor is only called of you do something with the argument that implicitly or explicitly constructs a new object.

The second line in your demo function is unnecessary: `A()` is already a prvalue.

Comment: I had prvalue before but miscorrected it to xvalue. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) agrees with you.